# Integer programming: if a or b then a, b, and c

Tags: logic, integer-programming, binary-operations

I'm writing a mixed integer programming (MIP) constraint where my $\color{blue}{\texttt{binary variables}}$ are $a, b,$ and $c$ to meet the following condition:
$$ (a \lor b) \to (a \land b \land c)$$
My equation so far is:
$$
3a + 3b \ge a + b + c
$$
I am getting some erroneous results. Is it possible to develop such an equation?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a linear constraint, or can it be quadratic?

Comment: @ItsmeMimi it has to be linear

Comment: @dassouki There is a logical problem in your condition. IF $a=1$ and $b=0$ on the LHS, then it doesn´t make sense that b on the RHS should has the value 1. You should think your constraint over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another binary variable $y$ and use the set of constraints
$$y\geq a+b,$$ 
$$a\geq y,$$ 
$$b\geq y,$$
$$c\geq y.$$

If you want to reduce the number of additional constraints down to two, 
$$a+b+c\geq 3a\quad \text{and}\quad a+b+c\geq 3b$$ would do the trick.

However, you can't reduce it down to one *and* have that constraint be linear, for the following reason:
Any linear constraint is of the form $$x a +yb+zc\geq 0,$$ and since you want it to be violated for $(a,b,c)\in\{(0,1,1),(1,0,0)\}$, your coefficients have to satisfy $y+z<0$ and $x<0$. Summed together, these observations however imply that 
$$x + y + z<0,$$ meaning your constraint cannot hold for $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: I did that before and the problem is that I have 4,000 sets of triplet variables, so by doing it that way, I tripled my constraints. I was trying to make things a bit more efficient

Comment: I see. You can do with two constraints: $a+b+c\geq 3a$ and $a+b+c\geq 3b$, but I don't see an even shorter way.

Comment: by adding another binary variable, what kind of impact would that have on efficiency ?

Comment: @dassouki: I think it really depends on your solver. A good solver may internally reduce the four constraints (+additional variable) down to two, but you could directly use the two constraints mentioned above.

Comment: @dassouki: If my answer solved your problem, would you mind accepting it by clicking the green checkmark?